# How to represent build number in NPM version?

Tags: node.js, npm, versioning

I would like to attach a build number to my project in package.json. I'm looking for the best way to do so.

I've found that node-semver recognizes a string as a build number if preceded by '+'. For example this would be build '123'.

> 1.0.0+123

However, the NPM version module will also accept this format, but trims off the build number in package.json. How should I go about representing the build number in package.json?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`+` is indeed the way to represent build numbers. But having different builds of the same version does not make sense from an npm semver perspective. So stripping out the build number makes a certain amount of sense.

If you are doing different builds because these are a series of prereleases, use `-` instead of `+`. `npm version prerelease` will increment `1.0.0` to `1.0.1-0`. Another `npm version prerelease` will increment to `1.0.1-1`.

Comment: Ok. It seems like it's best to strip out the build number. I hesitate to represent it as 'prerelease' due to a greater build having precedence over a lower one.

Comment: `But having different builds of the same version does not make sense from an npm semver perspective`

I disagree, they already allow it with `-`, so what "makes sense" is to simply honor semver as they claim that they do.  This smells like a bug.  For now I guess I'll use invalid minus signs to bump versions. :/

Comment: Asked the `npm` team for justification as to this decision here: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1479

Comment: @tresf Disagree if you want, but [the semver spec](https://semver.org/) says they are right. An appended `-` is not "invalid". The spec says `-` denotes a prerelease version. Meanwhile the spec also says that `+` denotes build metadata and "MUST be ignored when determining version precedence." They are not merely "claim[ing]" to honor semver. They're literally abiding by the spec here.

Comment: @tresf Although if all you're saying is that the `+` appended build metadata should be preserved and why the heck don't they do that...that's a good question, although the answer might be to avoid the impression that it's relevant when determining version precedence. I don't have an opinion one way or the other as to whether that's a good reason.

Comment: @tresf And just to be clear: Since `+` appended metadata is irrelevant for version precedence purposes, having multiple versions that differ in build metadata only would be a violation of semver. It means you have different versions of the library (or whatever) that use the same version number, and there's no way to determine which one has precedence. That's why I say that having different builds of the same version number makes no sense from a semver perspective.

Comment: `having multiple versions that differ in build metadata only would be a violation of semver` yeah, this conversation is very similar to the bug report.  My argument -- no longer against npm -- is the real world use-case is very different. I was wrong to argue that `+<build>` being ignored is incorrect, but after watching large projects abuse `-<build>`as a result (which I too will start doing) or use `+<build>` as necessary indicators, there's a need with no solution.  As a result, I too will start using `2.1.1-0`, `2.1.1-1` my own versions can be refactored to strictly adhere.

Comment: `having multiple versions that differ in build metadata only would be a violation of semver.`

Comment: Just because the meta tag is not applied to sorting, does not render it irrelevant. It is in fact a communications channel between the publisher and the consumer and should not be stripped from the string.  This seems to be a case of developers thinking they know best how their customers should behave.